# Can I still find D-Dog after mission 5?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

[The IGN Wiki states that D-Dog can be found during missions 3, 4 and 5.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain/D-Dog) However, I am up to mission 12, and I still have not encountered him.

I have tried returning to the mentioned locations, in free roam mode, but I still do not encounter him. I am not confident I have searched correctly, and if I have gone at the correct time of day. I also tried repeating the missions, but still, no luck.

Am I doing something wrong, is there any other way to find D-Dog, or have I lost the ability to find him completely?

Answer (score 3):

As is mentioned, in the comments;

You can find D-Dog by traveling to the starting locations **before** actually starting the mission. While it might involve a small amount of luck, D-Dog should show up as you approach the mission start zones for missions 3, 4 or 5.

To help in locating him, listen out for his yelping.